# Referencing value from module output (object map)

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to figure out a nifty way to generate randomised secrets in Azure Key vault using Terraform. Where i'm a bit stuck is when i want to use the generated secrets in other modules. The output of the secrets are as object map, and i cannot figure out the right syntax to reference the generated secrets in other modules.

For some specifics:

In the Keyvault module, i'm generating secrets like this, empty strings generates a new secret:

```
# Generate a random password
resource "random_password" "password" {
  for_each         = var.secrets
  length           = 20
  min_upper        = 2
  min_lower        = 2
  min_numeric      = 2
  min_special      = 2
  override_special = "!@#$*()-_=+[]{}<>:"
  keepers = {
    name = each.key
  }
}

# Create Azure Key Vault secrets
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  for_each     = var.secrets
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key-vault.id
  name         = each.key
  value        = lookup(each.value, "value") != "" ? lookup(each.value, "value") : random_password.password[each.key].result
  tags         = var.tags
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault.key-vault,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.default_policy,
  ]
}
```

The var.secrets is a map defined like this:

```
variable "secrets" {
  type = map(object({
    value = string
  }))
  description = "Define Azure Key Vault secrets"
  default     = {}
}
```

An populated like this:

```
kv-secrets = {
  secret-x = {
    value = ""
  }
  secret-y = {
    value = ""
  }
  secret-z = {
    value = ""
  }
}
```

The secrets are defined as outputs for the Key vault module like this:

```
output "key-vault-secrets" {
  value = values(azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret).*.value
}
```

Now let's say i would like to use a generated secret in other modules of my terraform project, a PSQL DB perhaps:

```
module "psql" {
  source              = "./modules/psql"
  psql_server_name    = var.psql_server_name
  location            = var.location
  prefix              = var.prefix
  environment         = var.environment
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  administrator_login          = var.administrator_login
  administrator_login_password = ?module.keyvault.key-vault-secrets?
  ..
  ..
}
```

Does anyone know how to reference the generated secret assigning the value to "administrator_login_password"? Or am i approaching this wrong.

cred: https://gmusumeci.medium.com/how-to-manage-azure-key-vault-with-terraform-943bf7251369

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? What errors do you get?

Comment: I guess it's finding the right syntax to fetch a specific secret from the 'module.keyvault.key-vault-secrets' output.  for example i would like to do something like this: ' administrator_login_password = module.keyvault.key-vault-secrets["secret-x"].value'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `module.keyvault.key-vault-secrets["secret-x"].value'` syntax, then your output should be:

```
output "key-vault-secrets" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret
}
```

Comment: Nice, it worked as intended. Thanks alot!